# Locking a row for the duration of the inner transaction

Tags: django, transactions, locking

Consider:

```py
with transaction.atomic():
    ...
    with transaction.atomic():
        row = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().get(...)
        ...
    # I need the lock on the row to be released here
    ...
# It is actually released here, which is not what I need
```

As [this article](https://seddonym.me/2020/11/19/trouble-atomic/) puts it:

> In many database engines, such as PostgreSQL, there’s no such thing as a nested transaction. So instead Django implements this using a single outer transaction.

I have confirmed that the lock is released only when the *outer* transaction ends. How can I achieve the effect explained in the comments in the above code block, i.e. that a row locked in the inner transaction become released upon the completion of that transaction?

P.S. Since I was asked in the comments to explain how one might be interested in such a thing, here is the background. Users of my website submit videos. My Django backend does some heavy processing and stores the results in the database. The first transaction is to lock the row corresponding to the video being processed. This is done to avoid performing the computation twice if the same video is submitted by two users at the same time (the videos come from the same collection). In such a case, the second request will wait and then return the results of the computation done in response to the first request. On the other hand, when two users submit two different videos, then both computations should proceed. However, as part of the computation, I invoke AWS Lambda. Since only a certain number of environments are kept warm, I track in the database the number of environments currently in use. The nested transaction is for updating that number correctly.

Comment: Since, PostgreSQL doesn't support nested transactions you can either leverage another external locking mechanism or implement an Optimistic Lock.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? It's hard to think of a case in which you want to release lock, but still be inside transaction

Comment: @BartoszStasiak I have included the background for my problem.